# x-axis line doesnot stretch for entire graph (svg graph)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a stacked barchart on [codepen](https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/qBXvzQd)

If you notice the x-axis of the chart, it only is available for half of the barchart. Any change i do, the line does not extend till the end of the barchart.

screenshot

[image]

This is the code which affects the x-axis line of the graph

```
 <g class="grid y-grid" id="yGrid">
     <line x1="90" x2="1505" y1="490" y2="490"></line>
 </g>
```

I tried changing the x2 value to a higher value but no effect.

There is one more thing i am trying to achieve. Its the x coordinates and y-coordinates for the entire graph as we have in below example.
Can someone please shed some light on how to get this on the graph

[image]

Comment: Each bar is a separate SVG. I'd suggest rewriting this so there's one `<svg>` element that contains all the bars. Drawing the axes will then be much more straightforward.

Comment: @RobertLongson- i tried putting everything in one svg but was not able to achieve it. Can you highlight what needs to be done to put all in one svg

Comment: One <svg> with a load of rect elements in it and some text elements. I'm afraid you'd need to show me your attempt if you want more than that.

Comment: sure, i will try to put another codepen with my attempt of putting everything on one svg.

Comment: You are putting yourself through a lot of trouble trying to hand draw very standard graphs. d3 is really the tool you should be reaching for.

Comment: I have used D3, apexcharts, recharts for most of the react projects i have worked for. The only reason i am using plain svg is because i need the charts to be displayed in an email. All third party libraries are not imported when sending chart data in email. So in case of 3rd party library, charts dont show up in an email but plain svg does show up

Comment: You've probably already thought of this, but why not use d3 to generate the graph, then grab the rendered SVG?

Comment: @MichaelMullany- i didnt think of using that way. thanks for the suggestion. wil try